# Populating your text area from the database on selecting the dropdown

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, jsp

> i have table vendortable with vendorid, vendorname, vendoraddress as attributes.
>   i am not able to populate the data from database in the textarea using jquery,ajax.

amateur, PLEASE HELP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Generate</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
```

> this works properly when location is selected the venue dropdown is
>
> automatically populated with the values from the database

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#locid').change(function(event) {
                    var locs = $("select#locid").val();
                    $.get('venue', {locationid:locs}, function(response) {
                        var select = $('#venid');
                        select.find('option').remove();
                        $.each(response, function(index,value) {

$('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#locid').change(function(event) {
                    var locs = $("select#locid").val();
                    $.get('venue', {locationid:locs}, function(response) {
                        var select = $('#venid');
                        select.find('option').remove();
                        $.each(response, function(index,value) {


    $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

> the below code is not working .on selecting the vendorfrom the dropdown i want the data to be populated automatically in the textarea in vendor address.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#vendorid').change(function(event) {
                var adds = $("select#vendorid").val();
                $.get('vendor', {vendorid:adds}, function(response) {
                    var select = $('#vendoraddress');
                    select.find('textarea').remove();
                    $.each(response, function(index,value) {
                        $('<textarea>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"  >
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"> <img alt="Brand" src="slideshow/img.png" style="height: 40px; display: inline-block; margin-top: -5px"> </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">Generate POR</a></li>
            <li><a href="Update\Adminlogin.html">Update POR</a></li>
            <li><a href="video.html">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>

        </ul>

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group" id="demo">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group" id="txt1" style="color: aliceblue; margin-top: -5px"  >

            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</nav>

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="row">
            <form>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                            <label>P O Date</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                            <label>Category</label>
                            <select class="form-control" >
                                <option>Technology</option>
                                <option>Business</option>
                                <option>Development</option>
                                <option>Process</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                            <label>Location</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="locid" id="locid" >
                            <option value="-1"> select </option>
                                <option value="1">Bengaluru</option>
                                <option value="2">Mumbai</option>
                                <option value="3">Pune</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                            <label>Type of training</label>
                            <select class="form-control" >
                                <option>RBI</option>
                                <option>PST</option>
                                <option>Org needs</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                            <label>Venue Details</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="venid" id="venid" >
                            <option value="-1"> select </option>
                                <option></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                            <label>Vendor</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="vendorid" id="vendorid" >
                                <option value="1">Pragati</option>
                                <option value="2">Synerget</option>
                                <option value="3">blah</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>



                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Vendor Address</label>

                              <textarea placeholder="Vendor Address Here.." rows="3" class="form-control" id="vendoraddress"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Billing Address</label>
                                <br>
                                    Billing Address :<br>
                                    Quinnox Consultancy Services Ltd.;<br>
                                    Unit 170,SDF VI, SEEPZ SEZ,<br>
                                    Andheri(East), Mumbai-400096<br>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped  table-hover" align="center">
                                        <thead class="thead-inverse">
                                             <tr>
                                               <div class="form-group">

                                                    <th>Subject</th>
                                                    <th>Faculty</th>
                                                    <th colspan="2" align="center">Date</th>
                                                    <th>Days</th>
                                                    <th>Batch Size</th>
                                                    <th>Rate per day</th>
                                                    <th>Approx Expected value(INR)</th>
                                                </div>
                                             </tr>
                                        </thead>

                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <td><input type="text"/></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text"/></td>
                                                    <td><input type="date"/></td>
                                                    <td><input type="date"/></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text"/></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text"/></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text"/></td>
                                                    <td><input type="text"/></td>
                                                </div>
                                             </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                         <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row">

                            <tr>TOTAL :</tr>

                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                    <h4>Terms and condition : </h4>
                                    <p>
                                        Payment     : As per discussion<br>
                                        Taxes       : As applicable<br>
                                        Delivery    : As per given schedule<br>
                                    </p>

                                    <br>
                                    <br>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="container-fluid">

                                <p><b>*</b>Travel ans accomodation of outside trainings will be borne by quinnox on actuals</p>
                                <p><b>*</b>Bills to be submitted for the same</p>
                                <br>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row"> 

                            <br>                           
                            For <b>Quinnox Consultancy Services Ltd.</b>
                            <br>
                            </div> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row"> 
                            <br>
                               Authorized Signature :
                               <br>
                               <br>
                               <br> 
                               <br>
                               <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>



            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: No there is no error in the console.Everything is working other than populating the textarea with the values in the database.

Comment: What is the response of your servlet `/vendor?vendorid=3`, when you call it directly in the browser?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Then you can accept it and upvote it, by clicking on the check-mark and arrow-up on the left side. If you still have trouble, please provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the response of your servlet i.e. `/vendor?vendorid=3` is a proper json.

**The issue in your javascript:**

```
$.get('vendor', {vendorid:adds}, function(response) {
    var select = $('#vendoraddress');
    select.find('textarea').remove();
    $.each(response, function(index,value) {
        $('<textarea>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
    });
});
```

- use proper name it is not "select". (this is a copy paste error)

  - instead of `var select = $('#vendoraddress');`
  - use `var textarea = $('#vendoraddress');`
- no need to remove the textarea childern

  - instead of `select.find('textarea').remove();`
  - just empty the value  `textarea.val('');`
- don't add textareas inside of textarea

  - instead of `$('<textarea>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);`
  - and the new values to the textarea `textarea.val(textarea.val() + value + "\n");`

**The working code:**

```
$.get('vendor', {vendorid:adds}, function(response) {
    var textarea = $('#vendoraddress');
    textarea.val('');
    $.each(response, function(index,value) {
        textarea.val(textarea.val() + value + "\n");
    });
});
```

I have tested it with a response `{"1": "Blah 1", "2": "Blah 2"}` and content-type `"application/json;charset=UTF-8"`

**Why you get this error**

Because the code was designe for a select, that have option-tags a children :

`<select><option></select`>

But Textarea-Tag have just text inside:

```
<textarea>text</textarea>
```